# creating a tabmenu UI using v-tabs

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I want to create a certain UI using vue.js which essentially looks like this. I have been able to create the first tab menu successfully using v-tabs and v-tab-items as this is the default design, but I cant figure out how to create the second style of tab menus. I have tried overriding the default css to create a white "bottom slider" and a v-divider to create the divider. My "bottom slider" always gets hidden by the v-divider when I want the v-divider to be hidden by the "bottom slider", which would be white. Z-index doesn't seem to help either. Is there an easier way to create this kind of UI?

[image]